# Zombie process when calling Popen and then Kill()

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a bit of an issue with a unit test; where in the setup I check if a process is running, and if it is not, I use Popen to run it.

In the `teardown()` I call `myprocess.kill()`, so I get a clean state for each test.

This works fine only the first time; because when I call the kill command on that process; it end up in zombie state (Z+); and this means that to get rid of it, I need to kill also the unit test class, since the Popen is originated in the setup phase of the testcase.

Is there a way to work around this? I call the test using pytest, passing the unit test python script as parameter.

```
class Mytest(unittest.TestCase)

    running_process = ""    

    def setUp(self):
        command = "~/myprocess"
        self.running_process = Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)

    def test_tryprocess(self):
        #do something 

    def test_tryprocess_again(self):
        # do something else

    def tearDown(self):
        self.running_process.kill()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the culprit: when I call Popen I also call shell=True. This will create a bond with the process, so it will hang until the shell is killed too.

To solve the problem, remove the `shell=True` from the call and it works fine.